# Does a graviton impart negative momentum?

Tags: general-relativity, momentum

Picture a massive system on an axis. If a graviton is generated and emitted by a system in the positive direction, will that system also be accelerated in the positive direction? Another system feeling the effect of the first system's gravitation moves towards that system (it absorbs the graviton and moves in the negative direction). The end effect is that the two systems attract each other. But, for this to happen, the traveling graviton must carry negative momentum to conserve the momentums of each emission and absorption events. Is this correct?

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/2000-01/948729425.Ph.r.html) out. It's about photons, but the analogy should hold.

Comment: In fact, I would highlight the following sentence from @cag's link: *The "moral" to be learned from all of this is that the lines in Feynman diagrams are not to be thought of as literal trajectories of real particles*.